# MPI - How do I get counts from local arrays into global array?

Tags: c++, arrays, mpi, global, local

I am trying to implement an MPI program for counting sort. I have sent each rank a local counts array to use. When I send them back to the master process, how do I make sure that all of the local arrays are added into the global array? I have seen `MPI_Reduce` for getting a total sum of the array but I need a sum for each individual cell.

Example:

```
array = {4,0,3,2,2,1,4,1,3,2,4,3,4,3}

countslocal1 = {1,1,2,3,4}
countslocal2 = {0,2,1,1,0}

countsglobal = {1,3,3,4,4}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `MPI_Reduce` does exactly what you need. It does not get the total sum of an array, but the sum of each individual cell. Or to cite the [MPI 3.1 standard](http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report.pdf):

> Each process can provide one element, or a sequence of elements, in
>   which case the combine operation is **executed element-wise on each**
>   **entry** of the sequence.

Comment: Thank you so much I'm not sure why I wasn't understanding that it did it per element in the array. My mind was stuck in openmp world still I think.